# jQuery, ajax, json, php parsererror

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, parse-error

I'm trying to get an ajax request running, but I get a parsererror.
This is my Javascript Code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'insertuser.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                nickname: $('input[name=nickname]').val(),
                passwort: $('input[name=passwort]').val()
            },
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("XMLHttpRequest", XMLHttpRequest);
                console.log("textStatus", textStatus);
                console.log("errorThrown", errorThrown);    
            }
        });
```

Thats the php file:

> $return['error'] = false;
>     $return['msg'] = "juhuuu";
>
> echo json_encode($return);

This is the console.log:

XMLHttpRequest Object
textStatus parsererror 
errorThrown SyntaxError

Thats what the .php echos:
{"error":false,"msg":"juhuuu"}

I hope someone has an idea :)

Comment: sendt data by  `var str = $(this).serialize();` adn in php `parse_str($_POST["data"],$array);`

Comment: Did you try adding a content type header in your PHP like: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`?

Comment: dataType jsonp and the header thing don't work..

Comment: Okay, I fixed it! :)
I only had to remove all the HTML content in my php file, like <html>, <body>, <header> and so on... now it works!

Answer (score 0):

This answer may or may not help somebody else. But I had a similar problem with a jQuery ajax json parse error. My form wouldn't send an email and was returning the parse error via jQuery.

**jQuery**

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process-form.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(response) {

        if(response.status == "success") {

        } else if (response.status == "error") {

        }
  });
```

**PHP**

```
if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || !preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/',$email) || !preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'status' => 'error'
                //'message'=> 'error message'
            ));
        } else {
            $send = mail($sendTo, $subject, $message5, $headers, '‑fexample@example.com');
            $sendText = mail($sendToPhone, '', $txtmsg, 'From: example <noreply@example.com>\r\n');

            // insert into db
            $formName = $_POST['name'];
            $queryIn = "INSERT INTO database pseudo code";

            //execute the query. 
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $queryIn);
            if (!$result) {
                printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
                exit();
            }

        }
if($send){
            echo json_encode(array(
                'status' => 'success'
                //This is the message the .ajax() call was looking for but it never posted because there was a MySQL error being printed to the browser along with it. 
            ));
}
```

My issue was with my PHP page that the ajax call was going to (`process-form.php`). I was emailing the form data with the PHP `mail()` function and inserting the web form data into a `MySQL` Database. My PHP checks for `mail()` send success and prints the success message to the screen (which is what the `jQuery .ajax()` call is looking for. But my `php/mysql` was throwing an error and printing the error on the screen instead of the "success" message it was supposed to display. So my `jQuery .ajax()` call was trying to read a `PHP json_encode()` encoded array and it was getting the `MySQL Error` instead. Once I fixed my MySQL Error everything worked perfectly.